# My computer keeps shutting off when I'm not using it

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

This is what the system log says when the "are you sure you want to shut down?" message comes up:

```
Sep 26 21:06:25 new-host-2 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[95] (com.zeobit.MacKeeper.Helper):
Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Why does my computer shutdown if I'm not using using it consistently?

Answer (score 1):

The suspicious part is reference to `MacKeeper`. From my perspective it is little more than bloatware set to look shiny and capture your wallet. It may very well be what is causing your PC to "behave so thoughtfully" and shut itself down on idle timelimit. Even you you attempted to remove it in the past, it is likely still around. You have two options:

1. Look at the program's options if you must keep it. Attempt to keep it form shutting down your mac after a set amount of idle time.
2. If you have removed MacKeeper, you must go deeper to remove all of its last vestiges. [Follow MacKeepers uninstallation instructions](http://help.mackeeper.zeobit.com/Manual/GettingStarted/UninstallingMacKeeper.html). However, that might not be enough.

You may need to look for and delete the following folders and files:

```
/Library/Application Support/MacKeeper
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.AntiVirus
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.plugin.AntiTheft.daemon
Home/Library/Caches/com.zeobit.MacKeeper
Home/Library/Caches/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.Helper
Home/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.Helper
Home/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.plugin.Backup.agent
Home/Library/Preferences/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.plist
Home/Library/Preferences/com.zeobit.MacKeeper.Helper.plist
```

Finally go into your user account control panel and look for any MacKeeper, zeobit, 911, or 911bundle accounts. In fact you may consider useing `grep -i` or `find` to look for any file and folder that is named with MacKeeper, zeobit, 911, or 911bundle in it. Remove them.

**NOTE WELL:** I have just recommended deleting files and folders from sensitive areas of your Mac. Please back up your data properly using Time Machine at the least. Pratice restoring backups and know where your data is and where it is not at all times. Your mileage may vary. No warranty is implied. Pictures have been enlarged to show texture.